# Multiple transparent background images

Tags: html, css, background-image, opacity, transparent

I have two background jpeg images that are repeated vertically across the entire left and right borders of my website.

Here is my code:

```
.gradients {
background-image: url("outer-gradient.jpg"), url("outer-gradient-horizontal-flip.jpg");
background-position: top left, top right;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

<body>
  <div class="gradients">
    <div> website content in here </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is what it looks like:

[left and right background images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePNfK.png)

I need a way to make both of these jpegs transparent.

Please don't suggest I just use CSS gradients, I cannot use CSS Gradients because of the color complexity needed to make the left and right images the way they were.  These jpegs have hundreds of colors for a richer gradient than any CSS Gradient could make.

I've seen methods of making a single background image transparent by adding an opacity div in front or behind it.  How would I do this for my .gradient div, when I have two background images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a way to make both of these jpegs transparent.

As you can't simply give `opacity` to the `gradients` div, which would affect the website content as well, you could use pseudo elements, like this, which will not effect the website content

```css
.gradients {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 60px;         /*  for this demo, push the content off the image  */
}
.gradients::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;             /*  width of your jpg file  */
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50/00f);
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}

.gradients::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;             /*  width of your jpg file  */
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50/f00);
  background-position: top right;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="gradients">
    <div>
      website content in here<br>
      website content in here<br>
      website content in here<br>
      website content in here<br>
      website content in here<br>
      website content in here<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you!  You fixed my problem! :)

Comment: You are a life saver! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what this means:

> These jpegs have hundreds of colors for a richer gradient than any CSS Gradient could make.

If you can make them in Photoshop, you can make your gradients in CSS. A gradient is by definition hundreds of colors, as it transitions from one to another (and potentially another). The screenshot you've shared is *definitely* able to be reproduced using CSS gradients.

However, since you've asked to rule that out, I'd suggest using 24-bit PNGs instead of JPGs. 24-bit PNGs have an alpha transparency channel which would allow you complete control over how transparent they are overall, and how transparent they are per-pixel. There is no `background-transparency` property at this point, so what you're trying to accomplish can't be done with the HTML markup you have and CSS.

The third option is to have an empty div with `opacity` for your background:

```
<div class="gradients"></div>
<div>Website content here</div>
```

```
html { height: 100%; }

body { min-height: 100%; position: relative; margin: 0; }

.gradients {
  background-image: url('left.jpg'), url('right.jpg');
  background-position: top left, top right;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzLWgx), with CSS gradients because I don't have your JPG assets but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of ways:

1. You should put them in separate divs and place these divs underneath the main container / wrapper. You can css-position them accordingly.
2. You could work with actual .png images that allow for a transparency gradient
3. You could work with a background image that already has both the gradients and the desired bg-color in one file. Then you could make it background-repeat: repeat-y; and background-size: contain.